# 3D game engine for a beginner using C++

Tags: c++

Decided to try myself at gamedev, which game engine should i start working with? Or how should I develop my gamedev skills?

Have C++ experience, I have already started studying OpenGL programming, and I'm using only linux based distributives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panda3D seems to meet all your needs. you can see user comments in [DevMaster](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/engine_details.php?id=95) or check it's [home page](http://www.panda3d.org/)

you can use [these search results](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/list.php?search_id=1b3fbb0e9d9d1cc745d7924cdc0567e4) for more engines (a hint check only those with more than 30 commnets)

Answer (score 9):

You sound ready to start learning how game development is different from writing other software, with those skills.

The best advice I see repeated over and over from experienced developers is to **build a game, not an engine**.  What they mean is that starting out you should write games instead of spending all your time writing engines that end up with no game at the end.  Writing engines will come later once you've made a bunch of games.

Start small (something like Breakout), but build a complete game that's playable from beginning to end!  Then slowly add features to that game and learn new libraries and techniques to make those features work.  Very soon you'll know all about adding middleware to a project, what libraries are available, and your skills get better almost magically.

Now you can go look at engines and you will be able to decode what they offer and make some sense of why each one was designed differently.  And from here you can build more complex games, maybe with an engine or one you decide to finally write.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing a big post, but ended up deleting all of it. I think the best thing is you to look into the following, read the documents and see the feature list. See which suits you best.

Once I was on a quest to find the best engine for me, but there is not best. All has some strengths and weakness. I am prioritizing them -

1. [Irrlight](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) ,
   [Esenthel](http://www.esenthel.com/)(No Linux) ,
   [Leadwerks](http://www.leadwerks.com/werkspace/index.php?/page/products/_/tools/leadwerks-engine-r3) (No Linux) & 
   [Panda3d](http://www.panda3d.org/)
2. [C4 Engine](http://www.terathon.com/c4engine/index.php) & [Torque Game Engine](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3d)

Havn't evauated yet, [3DGameStudio](http://www.3dgamestudio.com/), [DX Studio](http://www.dxstudio.com/)

[Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) is a rendering engine. To make a game with it you have to work on the additional parts. But, it worth Checking.

i haven't seen mentioned it anywhere, but apart from documentation its great, [g3d engine](http://g3d.sourceforge.net/)

But, all of it is just a short list of what is available out there. Go [here, DevMaster 3d Engine List](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/) and see all the engine and their features. *Caution :* many information are old.

& if you love java, you can always choose [jMonkey Engine 3](http://www.jmonkeyengine.org) < I use it :) Its pipeline is shader based.

**I havn't checked them in a while. They might have drastic change in their feature set. So check them yourself.**